# Can SSRS Text Box Properties action option "Specify a report" expression include multiple reports and none?

Tags: vba, reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

In `SSRS`, my table column "Description" has several types of information.  Depending on the type I would like to create an action that directs to a different report throught the specified parameters. I have done so by creating an expression:

```
=IIf(Fields!REFCEX.Value Like " P*", "PODetail", IIf(Fields!Description.Value Like "Journal*", "JVDetail", ""))
```

My problem is that the above expression works only if there is a matching value but if there isn't a match (see "" above) I get an error.  Because there is no report with that name.  What I would like to do is to replace "" with something (`VBA` code?) that says there is no action. No report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a switch statement to accomplish the same, but use a 0 instead of "" for no report

```
=switch (Fields!REFCEX.Value Like " P*", "PODetail"
, Fields!Description.Value Like "Journal*", "JVDetail", 0)
```

Comment: Your suggestion of using a 0 instead of "" works! Though I used it in my nested IIF statements.